# Are there no italic fonts in Print Composer?

Tags: qgis

QGIS 1.7 doesn't seem to have an 'italic' choice when annotating a map in Print Composer, only 'regular' or 'bold' fonts, a rather surprising omission if correct.  Is there some other way to create an italic font in Print Composer?

Answer (score 3):

In 1.7.4 version, when I click **Item tab** on the right of print composer and select font button i get options to change to italic,bold and regular. Except for "System" font, i see the italic options for every other font. See screen below.

Are you using any versions prior to this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are we talking about grid labels here? For italics try changing the font to one that includes italic characters. Arial, for example :) Nick.

Comment: Changing to a different font worked.  Many thanks for both your responses and suggestions!